# Exponential fit returns an unreasonable amplitude but looks good when plotted

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to fit my exponential data, but I am unable to get a decent answer. I'm using scipy and the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
import scipy.optimize
import pylab


def exponential(x, a, k, b):
    return a*np.exp(-x/k) + b
def main():
    filename = 'tek0071ALL.csv'
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=14)
    t = df['TIME']
    ch3 = df['CH3']
    idx1 = df.index[df['TIME']==-0.32]
    idx2 = df.index[df['TIME']==-0.18]

    t= t[idx1.values[0]:idx2.values[0]]
    data=ch3[idx1.values[0]:idx2.values[0]]
    popt_exponential, pcov_exponential = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(exponential, t, data, p0=[1,.1, 0])
   # print(popt_exponential,pcov_exponential)

    print(popt_exponential[0])
    print(popt_exponential[1])
    print(popt_exponential[2])
    plt.plot(t,data,'.')
    plt.plot(t,exponential(t,popt_exponential[0],popt_exponential[1],popt_exponential[2]))
    plt.show()
    plt.legend(['Data','Fit'])
main()
```

This is what the fit looks like:

[image]

and I think this means that it's actually a good fit. I think my time constant is correct, and that's what I'm trying to extract. However, the amplitude is really giving me trouble -- I expected the amplitude to be around 0.5 by inspection, but instead I get the following values for equation `A*exp(-t/K)+C`:

```
A:1.2424893552249658e-07
K:0.0207112474466181
C: 0.010623336832120528
```

I'm left wondering if this is correct, and that my amplitude really ought to be so tiny to account for the exponential's behavior.

Comment: Can we back up a second?  You write that you expected the amplitude to be around 0.5.  Why?  Without knowing where that assumption came from, it's possible that you made a wrong deduction.  That graph *does* look really nice.

Comment: Did you try putting bounds on `A` for the fit? As there are two other parameters, they could be "absorbing" changes in `A`.  See `bounds=[[A.min, K_min, C_min], [A.max, K_max, C_max]]` in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)